# How can I use the "backup" word?

Tags: meaning

In french the English word *backup* is often used but for various actions.

In English does "**to perform a backup**" mean the action to restore a system from a previous state. Or can it be also used for the action to create the system image which will be used for restoration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A backup in general is something that you have and you can use in case your normal operation or plan fails. You do not *do* or *perform* such a thing.

In an IT environment, when you *create* your system image:

> you **create** a backup
>   you **make** a backup
>   you **take** a backup
>   you **perform** a backup

The "take" on I hear especially in database-environments; the "perform" seems to confuse very few people.

When you use the backup to restore the crashed system:

> you **restore** from a backup

Outside IT environments, you can also have backups.
A common occurrence is a backup plan, which you can *make* and then *have*. If the original plan fails, you can *put* your backup plan *into action*, or *execute* your backup plan.
Note that here you do something with the *plan*, not with the *backup*!

A backup can also be a person who can take care of your tasks and / or responsibilities when you are not able to do so. I would not advise to *execute* that person.

Comment: I disagree with "I think that *performing* a backup is very ambiguous." I've often heard this phrase used (in a tech context) and there was never any ambiguity about what it meant.

Comment: I agree that _very_ ambiguous was a bit strong. Some ambiguity does exist, as proven by the OP's answer. And especially in a tech environment I prefer these thing to be as clear as possible (I work in a _very_ international environment, and I don't want to risk a sysadmin misunderstanding me when I request a backup to be "done".) But yes, it is used, and "performing" _usually_ means "creating", that's true.

Comment: Consider also that backup can be a verb: "I backed up my hard drive." "Perform a backup" just means "do a backup". If you said "I performed a search" it means that you searched. Given that, I don't see how "performing a backup" could mean anything other than backing up.

Comment: Since backup operations consist of two parts, not everybody is aware of which part is performed and which part is not. That is how it can mean something else. For the rest I cannot look in the heads of people that have misinterpreted this (among others, the OP). I already agreed that it is usually clear :)

Comment: Hmm. Honestly I wouldn't consider "restoring from backup" to be part of "backing up" unless it was explicitly stated. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backup) and the [Oxford Dictionary (2/2.1)](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/backup) would seem to agree: *backup, or the process of backing up, refers to the copying and archiving of computer data so it may be used to restore the original after a data loss*. I take your point about non-native speakers possibly being confused - but you could say that about almost any word or phrase...

Comment: @oerkelens, I agree with starsplusplus:  "Backup" is NOT a 2-part operation, "backup" is a single operation and "restore" is a separate operation.

Comment: If I am the only one that sees possible confusion, it must be my bad :) I have removed that part, and added it to the list of correct examples :)

Comment: Maybe for English native there is no confusion, but for other people it can be. It's the purpose of my question to know what expression to use to disambiguate with anybody.

Answer (score 3):

In computer jargon, to "perform a backup" is to create a copy of your data that will be kept in case the original data is lost or corrupted.

If you copy this data back to the live system, this is called "restoring a backup" or "restoring from a backup".

So no, "performing a backup" does not mean restoring the data from the backup. It is the opposite direction.

Comment: I especially like the version with _from_: Restore **from** a backup.